# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode' error when attaching html to email

Tags: python, html, email, encoding, smtp

I'm trying to attach html into emails with a python script. I've been able to send them successfully however wanted to have more organized code. I created a function that has the HTML inside it as a string. However there seems to be an encoding issue when I attach it onto an email. I need help to figure where I need to set the encoding.

I read some other posts regarding this same error message and they all seem to add this line of code onto their string.

```
encode('utf8')
```

So I have tried attaching this onto where I think it needs to go, but have not been able to find any success.

This is what I have

```
    def EmailTemplate():
    test = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <p>Hi!<br>
           How are you?<br>
           Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
    """
def SendEmail(me, you):

    # me == my email address
    # you == recipient's email address
    # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = "You've gone over your credit limit"
    msg['From'] = me
    msg['To'] = you

    # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
    text = ''
    html = EmailTemplate()


    # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
    part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
```

This code worked when I had the HTML as a string. However I now added a function to try and do the same thing.

For Example this is what i had before and worked

```
html = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <p>Hi!<br>
           How are you?<br>
           Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
    """
```

So I tried to replicate that with the following.

```
html = EmailTemplate()
```

Then the Function is

```
def EmailTemplate():
    test = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <p>Hi!<br>
           How are you?<br>
           Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>
    """
```

I Expected the email to send as normal, since the function is the same thing. However i get this for the error message.

```
File "H:\Files\Projects\Python\Test\Htmlemail.py", line 34, in SendEmail
    part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')

File "C:\Users\vanle\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\email\mime\text.py", line 34, in __init__
    _text.encode('us-ascii')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

So I tried to add the encoding to the following line of code

```
part2 = MIMEText(html.encode('utf8'), 'html')
```

However i still get this error message

```
File "H:\Files\Projects\Python\Test\Htmlemail.py", line 34, in SendEmail
    part2 = MIMEText(html.encode('utf8'), 'html')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `EmailTemplate` function has no return statement and so is assigning `None` to your variable `html`. Adding `return test` to the end of the `EmailTemplate` definition should solve this.

```
def EmailTemplate():
    test = """\
        <html>
          <head></head>
          <body>
            <p>Hi!<br>
               How are you?<br>
               Here is the <a href="http://www.python.org">link</a> you wanted.
            </p>
          </body>
        </html>
        """
    return test
```